# Redis Cluster automatically failover

Tags: python, redis

I am testing [redis-py-cluster](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster) for using Redis cluster, per its usage example. When some node fails, Redis commands can fail. I have to reconnect to make it work.

I used to use pymongo to connect to a MongoDB replica set. I remember the client does not need to deal with nodes failures. Is there a way for redis-py-cluster to transparently detect cluster nodes changes and carry out Redis commands?